# Static member inside a function public inside namespace

Tags: javascript

How to make Static member inside a function public inside namespace

```
var myNamespace= new function()
{
    this.myClass= function Page()
    {
        this.MyStaticVar = "myValue";
    }
}

$("#block").html(myNamespace.myClass.MyStaticVar);
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/DSs6r/97/](http://jsfiddle.net/DSs6r/96/)

Please try it there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "namespace" shouldn’t be a function, and `this` isn’t right in either case.

```
var myNamespace = {
    myClass: function Page() {
    }
};

myNamespace.myClass.MyStaticVar = "myValue";
```

[(Updated jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/DSs6r/98/)

Comment: Why is `myClass` a named function? :)

Comment: @Jack: I have no clue. Ask Abc :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var ns = {
   Class: {
       myStaticVar: 'myValue' 
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The main, only really, issue here was that you used a named function instead of an anonymous one (`function Page()`). Without the name, your code works just fine:

```
var myNamespace = new function()
{
 this.myClass = new function()
 {
  this.MyStaticVar = "myValue";
 };
};
```

Here is a jsfiddle showing the code working: http://jsfiddle.net/DSs6r/101/

More than likely, you were looking for a setup like this:

```
var myNamespace = new function()
{
 var Page = function(){
     var MyStaticVar = "myValue";
     var MyDynamicVar = "";

     function SetDynamicVar(val){
      MyDynamicVar = val;  
     };

     function GetDynamicVar(){
      return MyDynamicVar;  
     }

     return{
         MyStaticVar: MyStaticVar,
         SetDynamicVar: SetDynamicVar,
         GetDynamicVar: GetDynamicVar
     };
 };
 this.myClass = new Page();
};
```

Which would allow stuff like this:

```
myNamespace.myClass.SetDynamicVar("someValue")
$("#block").html(myNamespace.myClass.GetDynamicVar());
```

and:

```
$("#block").html(myNamespace.myClass.MyStaticVar);
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DSs6r/102/